# mpiexec using wrong number of cpus

Tags: cluster-computing, mpich, mpiexec

I am trying to set up a MPI Cluster. But I have the problem that the number of CPUs added to the mpd.conf file is not correctly used.
I have three Ubuntu servers.
opteron with 48 Cores
calc1 with 8 Cores
calc2 with 8 Cores.

My mpd.hosts looks like:
`opteron:46

calc1:6

calc2:6`

After booting (mpdboot -n 3 -f mpd.hosts) the System is running.
mpdtrace -> all three of them are listed.

But running a Programm like "mpiexec -n 58 raxmlHPC-MPI ..." causes that calc1 and calc2 get to many jobs and opteron gets to few at the same time.
What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Bjoern

Comment: After starting mpiexec, opteron gets 20, calc1 19, and calc2 19 processes. That makes 58, the number I told mpiexec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround.
I used the additional parameter "-machinefile /path/to/mpd.hosts" for the mpiexec command. And now, all nodes are running correctly.
One problem I got was that I got following error message:

... MPIU_SHMW_Seg_create_attach_templ(671): open failed - No such file or directory ...

To fix it, I had to set the environment variable `MPICH_NO_LOCAL=1`

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out, you must pass the machinefile to both `mpdboot` and `mpiexec` in order to use per-host process counts.  The "open failed" issue is a known bug in MPD, the process manager you are using.  Note that the `MPICH_NO_LOCAL=1` workaround will work, but will probably result in a big performance penalty for intranode communication.

You are clearly using MPICH2 (or an MPICH2 derivative), but it's not clear what version you are using.  If you can, I would strongly recommend upgrading to either MPICH2 1.2.1p1 or (better yet) 1.3.1.  Both of these releases include a newer process manager called [hydra](http://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/mpich2/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager) that is much faster and more robust.  In 1.3.1, hydra is the default process manager.  It doesn't require an `mpdboot` phase, and it supports a `$HYDRA_HOST_FILE` environment variable so that you don't have to specify the machine file on every `mpiexec`.